# how to find address in memory without debugger?

Tags: ios, arm, disassembly

I studied the game code and came across the PurchaseDocument class and method, they send requests to the server, I tried to mark the request using Charles, it didn’t work, but disassembling the game code, the requests go to the server.

[**Here is the request sent to the server:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlA3g.png)

I'm interested in the part with Expression Attrinute Value "N"

[**Here is a part of the disassembled code that is responsible for the part highlighted in the request:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exchh.png)

The address of the line in memory is written to the "x1" register, but the debugger does not work for me to find out immediately what the address is.

I will be happy if they help me with the problem, my experience with arm is very small

Comment: If you just want to change the value `N`, then you don't need the address, you just need to patch the `LDR x1, ...` instruction with the value you want loaded to `x1` register

Comment: unfortunately the value that needs to be changed is string in this problem, as an idea, I wanted to take an int value and use the int to string translation function, then throw it into x1

Comment: What is thrown into `x1`? Address of the string _or_ the _character_ of the string in some kind of code number (eg ASCII number)?

Comment: I tested many times what comes there, with a high probability it is the address from memory, for example, if in "ldr x1, [x8, 0x250]" change 0x250 to 0x248, then in the request it will turn out that N = "0" instead of "1"

Comment: on one of the sites they helped me a lot, the fact is that there is another request to the server where N is represented as the price of the goods in the game, I managed to change "N":"1" to "N":"10"

Comment: I would suggest 3 ways: 1) Change the `ldr` instruction to your custom address; 2) Create a function at an empty space, then call to it, get it return value and set it into `x1` before calling the `set_N` function; 3) Disassembly the `set_N` function and inject the value you want there. Good luck!

Comment: Also, if possible, can you please provide the link to the other site? The site in which you said `on one of the sites they helped me a lot`

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/1178760 ok but use translate

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on the "but the debugger does not work for me to find out immediately what the address is."
I assume you do have access to a jailbroken device and can install `lldb` on it.

In this code (adjusting for executable load address changing under ASLR):

```
0x013e0c80 adrp x8, 0x2d71000
0x013e0c84 nop  //set breakpoint here
0x013e0c88 ldr x1, [x8, #0x250] //or here
```

You can inspect the memory like this:

```
x $x8+0x250
```

Comment: Yes, right now I'm studying lldb, so far I've set up debugserver, now I'm hiding, I solved the problem with breakpoints